# Encryption for passing password from Frontend to backend in Django Application

Tags: django, authentication, web-applications, cryptography, ldap

I am working on Django Project and I want to setup authentication using LDAP backend. I have a form in UI where user will be able to enter user name and password and this will be passed to LDAP backend for authentication. While passing data from UI form to LDAP backend. DO I have to use any encryption technique? If yes, what kind of and how? Thank you.

Comment: Use HTTPS. It is encrypted by default using TLS or SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Using HTTP over TLS will provide secure transmission.

If the server can provide the necessary secure connection over TLS then the communication is secure *in this day and age*. <sup>[1]</sup>

---

<sub><sup>[1]</sup> I humbly recognize the evolution of cybersecurity and cryptography.</sub>

Comment: HTTP or HTTPS? Thank you.

Comment: HTTPS is actually HTTP with Transport Layer Security (TLS).